# Cleveref. Disable 'nameinlink' for specific \cref{}

Tags: cleveref

How can I disable the `nameinlink` feature of `cleveref` for a specific `\cref` instance?

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> How can I disable the `nameinlink` feature of `cleveref` for a specific `\cref` instance?

I will assume that the `hyperref` package is loaded along with `cleveref`. Please advise if this is not the case.

I don't believe that the `cleveref` package offers a macro that would let you achieve your formatting objective *directly*. However, it's straightforward to achieve the desired effect by (a) switching from `\cref` to `\labelcref` and (b) inserting the required label word by hand.

For instance, let us assume that a document has two equations with labels `eq:1` and `eq:2` and that you wish to cross-reference these equations. If `cleveref` is set to output English language strings, the instruction

```
\cref{eq:1,eq:2}
```

will generate

> eqs. (1) and (2)

with the string "eqs." forming a hyperlink together with "(1)". (Aside: If you loaded `cleveref` with the option `noabbrev`, you would get "equations" instead of "eqs.".) However, there's nothing to stop you from writing either

```
eqs.\ \labelcref{eq:1,eq:2}
```

or 
    eqs.~\labelcref{eq:1,eq:2}

With either method, the word `eqs.` will *not* be part of the hyperlink. Observe that `~` inserts a non-breaking space between "eqs." and "(1)"; using a simple backslash-space sequence, in contrast, inserts an ordinary (i.e., breakable) space. The `~` method would be preferred if it's important to avoid having line breaks between an item's label (here: "eqs.") and its associated number.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1} a \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2} b \end{equation}

\cref{eq:1,eq:2}

eqs.\ \labelcref{eq:1,eq:2}
\end{document}
```